# What does an empty run queue entry points to?

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduling

I'm trying to figure out the technicalities of scheduling in Linux. What I can't figure out is what happens with those entries in the run_queue where there are no running processes. 
In the run_queue we have a bitmap, a counter, and the array of lists themselves. For a list that is empty because there are no running tasks with its priority, what do the next and prev pointers point to?

Comment: I don't have an authoritative answer, but chances are it's either "a null value" or "it doesn't matter".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about the `struct rt_prio_array` structure, empty lists have `next` and `prev` pointers that point to the `struct list_head` in the `struct rt_prio_array` itself.

This is true of all the `list.h` lists.  The `list_empty()` function is provided to test for this condition.